# Когда использовать SOAP протокол, а когда REST архитектуру в web? PHP JS

Tags: архитектура, rest, soap

Всем привет.
Я понимаю, что если придираться, то не совсем корректно сравнивать протокол и архитектуру(даже архитектурный стиль). Но все мы программисты и поэтому должны уметь решать нестандартные вопросы. :-)
Конечно, корректнее было бы сравнивать rpc и rest. Но будем честными - вряд ли кто-то работал за свою жизнь с какой-то другой реализацией кроме SOAP?
Прочитал очень много статей вроде rest vs soap и тому подобных, основное что узнал:
- rest очень легковесный и привязан к http, а soap тяжёлый и очень гибкий относительно используемых протоколов(хотя эта гибкость опять же ни к чему -  мы все работаем с http или https).
- очень грубо - в rest-архитектуре сервер даёт ответ в виде готового представления, который клиент должен просто вставить себе на странницу; в soap - клиент-сервер обмениваются сообщениями, которые ещё нужно раскодировать, чтобы получить результат.
- остальные отличия несущественны, т.к. rest-архитектуру можно реализовать и используя протокол soap.


Собственно вопрос - когда использовать rest, а когда soap?

Или это вообще два термина, которые не являются взаимоисключающими? То есть я могу проектировать restfull приложение, которое в каких-то случаях работает через soap?
Или есть какие-то требования когда нужно использовать только rest и больше ничего другого, что противоречит его принципам; а когда - только soap или любой другой  rpc-протокол; и может есть случаи в которых наоборот - желательно объединение двух технологий?
Пожалуйста, объясните, кто работает с этой темой. Спасибо!

Comment: Ребят, желательно бы конкретные примеры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, что всерьёз задумываться над тем, что выбрать (SOAP или REST) Вам в ближайшее время не придётся. На сегодняшний день REST де-факто уже практически вытеснил SOAP. ИМХО, единственное серьёзное преимущество последнего, это возможность цифровой подписи сообщений, из-за чего он пока ещё пользуется спросом в некоторых узких областях.

Если проект как-то связан с этими областями, то возможно, Вам придётся иметь дело с SOAP. Если нет, вряд ли Вы с ним столкнётесь.

Таким образом, выбор между REST и SOAP фактически определяется задачами, которые решает проект.

Comment: Отлично. Что за узкоспециализированные области? И в каких задача rest, а в каких - soap??? Можно конкретные примеры.

Comment: А, какие Вы хотите примеры? @O.O, Ваша позиция при выборе протокола основана только на специфике решаемой задачи, а есть ещё масса других нюансов. В частности, SOAP основан на XML и генерировать XML в несколько МБ чтобы передать строку из нескольких сотен байт мягко скажем накладно и по ресурсам и по трафику. В REST общий вес JSON (ставший традиционным формат по умолчанию) и вес самих данных вряд ли будут так сильно отличаться. Есть и другие нюансы.

Comment: REST прижился не просто потому, что это более новый стиль создания веб сервисов. Есть, конечно, enterprise системы, которые ещё используют SOAP. Но, это либо старые проекты, либо проекты в которых пока нет возможности от него отказаться по тем или иным причинам. Но, последние, повторюсь, сейчас редкость. Так, что по умолчанию можно смело использовать REST.

Comment: А какой может быть случай, чтобы проект не мог отказаться rpc в виде soap или тому подобного тяжёлого варианта(ну кроме тех случаев когда приложение пишется по 5 лет, когда проверенных временем альтернатив было мало и было страшно использовать что-то новое, т.к. цена ошибки дорога)

Comment: Ещё у меня предположение, что слабость(иногда слабость) rest - сервер не сохраняет состояние клиента. В случаях, когда, например, ведётся коллективная работа - это может быть минусом. Или я не так понимаю Communicate statelessly?

Comment: Если речь идёт о многопользовательском режиме, то эта проблема решается банальной авторизацией на токенах. А, на клиенте есть Local Storage.